# Switch for low voltage, high current Shape Memory wire

Tags: mosfet, switches, buck

I need a switch to allow current to pass through a wire to Joule heat it. This is a nickel-titanium wire (Shape Memory Alloy, SMA) which has been programmed to bend into a particular shape when heated. Unfortunately, this SMA wire is fairly large and rather low resistance (~0.6 ohm), so to heat it properly I am using about 3 amps but only 2 volts.

I would like to be able to turn the current on and off with a control signal as needed to maintain a desired temperature. Transistor solutions seem to be either too low current or too high VDS (> 5 V).

I have stumbled onto possibly two solutions, using PWM with an H-bridge, or using a buck converter, but I am having a hard time understanding why one would be better than the other or if they would even work.

Comment: How fast do you need to switch? Have you considered a relay (driven by a FET)? Could be cheaper than a power FET and have less power losses.

Comment: @yhyrcanus I had not considered that. The switching just needs to be fast enough to regulate the temperature within a couple degrees, so I'm guessing even ~10Hz is fine? For some reason in my head relays were all large and noisy, but this may be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 2V supply and your control signal is (say) 5V you can just use a beefy MOSFET.

For example, you could use an [IRL40B209](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irl40b209.pdf) which has a guaranteed Rds(on) of <1.6m\$\Omega\$ with 4.5V drive (Tj=25°C). That means it would drop only 5mV at 3A. 
That one is probably overkill (though not so unreasonably priced unless you're into vast quantity), but you get the idea.

If you need to create the 2V@3A supply from (say) 5V you could use a buck converter and simply switch the converter off and on using an enable pin or by jimmying the feedback voltage (assuming only one wire is used). A perfect buck converter would draw 1.2A to get your required 6W, so a real one might be more like 1.5A.

An H-bridge is typically pointless in switching a resistive load because polarity does not matter and you're doubling the losses and quadrupling the power device count for no good reason.

You could also directly PWM from a 5V supply (no inductor), however it would be drawing current in >8A pulses (which the supply would have to handle- peak power exceeding 40W). The on ratio would be 16% to get 2V RMS across the load from a 5V supply.

Any of the above methods would work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You bring up a good point I hadn't thought about, in that I eventually want to run this off of the same supply that the rest of the board is using, i.e., likely 5V or 12V.

Comment: Also, your post does bring up some additional *probably* stupid questions: 1) Do MOSFETs work properly with a power supply voltage that is lower than the driving voltage (VDS < VGS)? I was under the impression that VDS must be larger than VGS. 2) Do buck converters handle rapid toggling like that ok? Would there be any benefit to putting a FET after the buck converter to handle the switching there?

Comment: 1. Yes, provided Vgs is high enough they'll work fine. Otherwise they wouldn't turn on (when 'on' Vds is about 0V in this case, when off it's 2V). 2. You probably don't need to switch the output on/off rapidly. The regulator switching itself usually takes place at 50kHz-2000kHz to keep inductors small. 3. Sure, you could use one supply and multiple wires, and maybe in some case where you had to switch it rapidly (unlikely in this case).